# regex_search only selecting biggest substring that matches. Also type mismatch in regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

The regex_search here selects only the longest substring in this program as the output is the whole string data.
Is that the default behaviour?

Additionally if i pass the string without declaring it as a string first like this

```
regex_search("<html><body>some data</body></html",m,samepattern)
```

It throws an error of type mismatch .

Additionally if i only use without the additional 2nd parameter

```
regex_search("some string",pattern);
```

it works.

The whole code is shown below

```
#include<string>
#include<regex>
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   smatch m;
   string data{"<html><body>some data</body></html"};
   bool found = regex_search(data,m,regex("<.*>.*</.*>"));
   //If regex_seacrh("<html><body>some data</body></html",same as above)
   //it throws type mismatch error for this string in regex header
   cout<<(found?m.str():"not found");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [you don't parse HTML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3959454).

But if you do, you indeed have parameter mismatch in the call

```
smatch m;
bool found = regex_search("some data", m, regex("some regex"));
```

Corresponding [`regex_search()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) overload has to be:

```
template <class charT, class Allocator, class traits>
bool regex_search(const charT* str,
    match_results<const charT*, Allocator>& m,
    const basic_regex<charT, traits>& e,
    regex_constants::match_flag_type flags =
    regex_constants::match_default);
```

but `m` is of type [`smatch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) which is `match_results<std::string::const_iterator>`.

What you should do is to use `cmatch` instead of `smatch`:

```
cmatch m;
bool found = regex_search("some data", m, regex("some regex"));
```

**Update** as for your question about the longest match - you have to use non-greedy match qualifiers, that is e.g `.*?`

Comment: Yeah i just used that string for demo purposes i m not actually trying to parse any HTML